# Make this Regex work with negative lookahead

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I’m doing an html and bbcode parser. I have this regex that catches repeated groups from the inside-out:

```
$re = '/<b>((?:(?!<\/?b>).)*)<\/b>/is';
```

But I want to be able to match `<b class=”string”>text</b>` or any other attribute inside.
I was already doing it by using:

```
'/<b((\s)+?.*?)?\>(.*?)<\/b>/is'
```

But now when trying to join them and add the new negative lookahead, I cannot make it work.

I tried  `'/<b((\s)+?.*?)?\((?:(?!</?b((\s)+?.*?)?>).)*)<\/b>/is'`  but does not work properly, for this:

```
<b class=”string2”><b class=”string”>text</b></b>
```

It matches from the first b tag, and it shouldn’t. I would like to get:

```
<b class=”string2”>[b]text[/b]</b>
```

Comment: [Obligatory Regular Expressions are the wrong tool to parse html comment]

Comment: Please post the before and after string you want.

Comment: @nfnneil done added

Comment: @WillBarnwell and whats the right tool?

Comment: a html parser such as beautiful soup

Comment: Something I'm a little confused about, <b class=”string2”>[b]text[/b]</b> ...  why not convert both to [b][b]text[/b][/b]  Are you sure you only want the inner one changed?

Comment: @nfnneil shure, I do loops, but the first loop would do what I show in the example.

Comment: Updated it, go ahead and look at the new code.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/book.bbcode.php

Answer (score 1):

This will all < b > with [b]:

```
<?php

$str = '<b>test</b><b class=”string2”><b class=”string”>text</b></b>';
$prev = '';
while ($prev != $str) {
    $prev = $str;
    $str = preg_replace("/<b[ a-z0-9\"'\=”]*?>(.*?)<\/b>/is","[b]$1[/b]",$str);
}
echo $str;

?>
```

Comment: First problem I see is it does not work for <b> without attributes, second problem is this matches <blockquote></b>, wich can be fixed adding <b((\s)+?.*?)?\> but the first problem still exist.

Comment: But now with (.*?) again in the middle it does not parse HTML as it should, instead of matching HTML tags from the inside-out, it matches the first open tag and first closing tag even with more open tags inside, and that's not how HTML works. That is the trickie part.